# Short tutorial on Mysql Explain

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out how to use Mysql Explain.

I ran explain on the following query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `g`.`id`,
            `a`.id as account_id,
            `a`.currency as `currency`,
            `a`.`balance` as `balance`,
            `b`.`id` as ba_id

    from `accounts` `a`
            inner join `groups` `g` on `a`.`owner_id`=`g`.`id` and `a`.`owner_type`='group'

            left join `bank_accounts` `b` on `b`.`owner_account_id` = `a`.`id`  AND `a`.`currency` = 'USD' AND b.state != 4

            where `a`.balance != 0 AND

            `g`.app_id != 0 AND

            `g`.`status` & 32 OR (`b`.`id` IS NULL);
```

I get back:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  g   ALL PRIMARY,id,app_id               1711249 
1   SIMPLE  a   ref owner_type_balance,owner,owner_type_currency    owner   72  wepay.g.id,const    1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  b   ref state,owner_account_id  owner_account_id    8   a.id    1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  c   ref state,owner_account_id  owner_account_id    8   a.id    1   Using where
```

How should I handle this output to make my query faster?

Comment: what are the datatype and size of id(groups) , owner_id (accounts) ?

Comment: And where is your table with the alias name of `c`?